# MyriadPro and MiKTeX (FontPro)

Tags: fonts, miktex, installing, font-encodings

I tried to install Myriad Pro as described by [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) (XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX aren't an option) because I couldn't build the files via cygwin and used GNU/Linux to build all necessary files and copied the files manually to my MiKTeX-directory (not the Main-directory) and I completed the installation as outlined on github. Under Linux I could compile a document without any trouble but it seemed not to work under windows... After repeating the installation (over and over) and updating MiKTeX etc. I found a wired behaviour the error doesn't appear under the standard TeX-classes but just in in Koma-Script (but not under TeX Live 2015 on Linux). And even under the koma-script-classes the file compiles if I set a `\part{}` (like `\chapter{}` or `\section{}`). The error seems to be linked to the font size of `\chapter{}` because without the chapter it compiles fine.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{MyriadPro}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\part{Introduction} 
Text $\dots$    
\chapter{Introduction}
Text $\dots$


\end{document}
```

Log-File:

```
    {C:/Users/Harry/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
chapter 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/MyriadPro-OsF/bx/n' in size <10.95> not avai
lable
(Font)              Font shape `T1/MyriadPro-OsF/b/n' tried instead on input li
ne 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/MyriadPro-OsF/bx/n' in size <20.74> not avai
lable
(Font)              Font shape `T1/MyriadPro-OsF/b/n' tried instead on input li
ne 10.
! Font T1/MyriadPro-OsF/bx/n/20.74=MyriadPro-Bold- at 20.74pt not loadable: Met
ric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.10 \chapter{Introduction}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

! Font \T1/MyriadPro-OsF/b/n/20.74=nullfont not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not
 found.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.10 \chapter{Introduction}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
```

[image]
[image]

Log-file with `\part`:

```
(C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\MyriadPro\MyriadPro-FontDe
f.sty
File: MyriadPro-FontDef.sty 2012/02/17 v0.3 font definition macros
))
\c@mv@tabular=\count96
\c@mv@boldtabular=\count97

part I.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/MyriadPro-OsF/bx/n' in size <10.95> not avai
lable
(Font)              Font shape `T1/MyriadPro-OsF/b/n' tried instead on input li
ne 8.
Package scrkbase Info: You've told me to use the font selection of the element
(scrkbase)             `partprefix' that is an alias of element `partnumber'
(scrkbase)              on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/MyriadPro-OsF/bx/n' in size <20.74> not avai
lable
(Font)              Font shape `T1/MyriadPro-OsF/b/n' tried instead on input li
ne 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/MyriadPro-OsF/bx/n' in size <24.88> not avai
lable
(Font)              Font shape `T1/MyriadPro-OsF/b/n' tried instead on input li
ne 8.
[1
```

I think the behaviour seems a bit odd, does anyone have a idea? (esp. because it works under TeX Live on a Linux machine )

**Update**: List of the names of the files created by FontPro under GNU/Linux

[ls-r](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=01930866255667385462)

**Udpate2**

```
Running hbf2gf.exe...
hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4)

Couldn't find `MyriadPro-Bol.cfg'
miktex-maketfm: No creation rule for font MyriadPro-Bold-.

chapter 1.
! Font T1/MyriadPro-OsF/bx/n/20.74=MyriadPro-Bold- at 20.74pt not loadable: Met
ric (TFM) file not found.
```

By the way,  at least`MyriadPro-Bol.cfg` isn't created nor needed under Linux (TeX Live '15). Is it an error or something that's different in MikTeX?

**Update2**
[image]

---

**Update**3

What works best at least for me is just to use TeXlive under Windows and to create all the necessary font-files on a linux machine and copy them into the right texlive folder and than to update the texlive installation as the described by fontpro.

Comment: The font is definitely not installed properly.

Comment: What's preventing you from using XeLaTeX and/or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: Well, mostly the poor support of `microtype` (esp. for XeLaTex) but I'm using LaTeX for my Thesis and the template as well as some-packages properly won't work with LuaLaTeX (what I still use to externalize `tikz`-plots in my thesis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FontPro requires tftopl.exe, pltotf.exe, vptovf.exe, and vftovp.exe.
MikTeX's version does not work.

I install cygwin, install LCDF tools from w32tex distribution, 
and also the above 4 programs from w32tex, and then run FontPro.
It works.

Comment: I used the FontPro scripts on a Linux machine to create all necessary font files (I updated the starting post to include them)

Comment: @harry haller: This seems to be typical of the type 1 font files not being found. Check if the fonts are mentioned in you personal/local `updmap.cfg`. If not, add the lines `Map minionpro.map` and `Map myriadpro.map` to the file, and in any case, run from the command line `updmap --verbose` (as administrator if you want all users to have access to the font).

Comment: As I said I followed the instruction as stated on the FontPro Github site. Additionally, MiKTeX is compiling the file for different `documentclasses` with different font sizes! How could `pdfLaTeX` do this without haveing the map-file? Anyway I added an image with the result in first thread entry.